# How to create a HarperDB table with lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nosql

I wrote the following Node.js code to create a table on [HarperDB Cloud](https://harperdb.io/product/harperdb-cloud/). This code executes perfectly when executed locally. I moved the same code to [AWS Lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Lambda), and alas, the code executed without any errors, but the table does not get created.

I suspect something wrong in the way I called lambda function, but I am unable to find out what's wrong. How can I fix it?

```
exports.handler = async (event,) => {

  var https = require('follow-redirects').https;
  var fs = require('fs');

  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'hostname': 'MyInstanceName-MyAccount.harperdbcloud.com',
    'path': '/',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic MyAuthoriztionCode',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'maxRedirects': 20
  };

  var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function (chunk) {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      console.log(body.toString());
    });

    res.on("error", function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  });

  var postData = JSON.stringify({
    "operation": "create_table",
    "schema": "MySchema",
    "table": "NewTable",
    "hash_attribute": "Id"
  });

  req.write(postData);
  req.end();

  const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify('Table created successfully!'),
  };

  return response;

};

/// AWS Lambda Function (Node.js code) ends here'''
```

Comment: (At 2021-10-12T121907Z+0 `https://harperdb.io/` was extremely slow (several *minutes*).)

Comment: This was featured in *[Podcast 383: A database built for a firehose](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/10/12/podcast-383-a-database-built-for-a-firehose/?cb=1)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because you are using a callback in an async lambda handler.

Try converting the lambda to a callback

`exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {}`

or use an async/await request library.